New Tab Opens Login Page Even When Already Logged In (Node-RED Session Issue)
I'm working on a Node-RED application, and I'm encountering an issue with session handling when opening a new tab in the same browser.
Here's what's happening:
I log in to http://localhost:1880/api/login in one tab, which successfully creates a session and sets a session cookie.
When I open a new tab and navigate to http://localhost:1880/api/login, it shows the login page again instead of redirecting to the dashboard or maintaining the session.
If I log in again from the new tab, it creates a new session. This new session overrides the session cookie in the browser, even though the database has multiple sessions for the same user.
When I open a new tab, the session should persist, and I should be redirected to the dashboard if already logged in.

Why are you explicitly going to /api/login? The editor will redirect you there if needed

Also edit question to include details of what authentication mechanism you are using.

We really can't help without the information I've asked for
